# Can I nest # inside $ to access environment variable and property variable in spring xml file?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-el

I have defined a environment variable in VM, -Denvironment=dev. And I can get this variable by using SpEl, #{systemProperties['environment']}. Meanwhile I have a property variable, dev.anything=someValue, defined in a property file. I can access this by using ${dev.anything}. However, ${#{systemProperties['environment']}.anything} just gives me dev.anything, instead of the expected value, someValue.

Comment: Try `${#{systemProperties['environment']} + '.anything'}`

Answer (score 0):

You can put property placeholders within SpEL but not vice-versa, or just use property placeholders.

`${${environment}.anything}}` will work -

```
@Value("${${bar}.foo}") 
String foo;`
```

with `-Dbar=x -Dx.foo=y`

results in foo containing `y`.

This works too....

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['${bar}' + '.foo']}")
String bar;
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I think your solution works. However, I just changed my design, e.g., split the properties into to different files, dev.properties, it.properties, prod.properties, and so on. So, the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer changes to <value>classpath:/proprty/${environment:dev}.properties</value>.